# Does the EVM execute a smart contract aagain after it has been deployed on the blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, evm, smart-contract-wallets

I understand that when deploying a smart contract on the blockchain in Ethereum, it is executed by the EVM. What I don't quite understand is after the contract is on the blockchain and we have an address to interact with it when we call and execute functions, does the EVM execute these commands to change the state of the contract? and is a new instance of the contract with the new state created and stored on a different address on the blockchain?

Comment: You can see Yongjian answer down below. Apart from that I would recommend going through this paper before starting on your SC journey - https://arxiv.org/pdf/2108.05513.pdf

Answer (score 0):

1. After the contract is on the blockchain and we have an address to interact with it and when we call and execute functions, the EVM does execute commands to change the state of the contract if the command does change the state of the contract.
2. No, a new instance of the contract with the new state is not created and stored on a different address on the blockchain when the EVM execute these commands to change the state of the contract. Changing the state does not require redeploying the smart contract, but changing the code does.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer was very healpful